# How to delete folder named '...'

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10

While messing around with a nodejs script, I was (accidentally) able to create a folder named '...'.
I am unable to delete it.
How can I delete it?!

It's quite ridiculous. Am unable to rename it (says another process is using it, tried restarting), unable to delete it (it just starts counting files indefinitely until Windows explorer crashes). It seems to be a recursive problem.

If I go into the folder, I get the same folder again!

[image]

Tried renaming the folder from the command line, but got this:

```
ren : An object at the specified path C:\Users\emimue\test\... does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ ren "..." "foo"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Rename-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Try using the \\?\ prefix to remove it from the CMD, like this:  `rmdir "\\\?\C:\Users\you\directory\..."`

Comment: Or wherever the directory is.

Comment: you are most likely not going to be able to remove it while the OS is running.  You will need to go into recovery mode with a command prompt.  Besides that "nodejs script, I was (accidentally) able to create a folder named '...'." seems like a security issue as it should not allow you to do that.